# Hibernate - How to get object reference

Tags: java

I'm reading data from .csv file and storing those values into one table.
For that table have a POJO class. that class has variable

```
   private Integer customerId;
```

mapping for that above property in hbm.xml file

```
     <property name="customerId" type="long">
        <column name="CUSTOMER_ID" />
    </property>
```

customer_id is equal to XXXX class id.
based on the customer_id, I need XXXX class object without querying manually.

can you guys please help on this
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why is it mapped as `Integer customerId` instead of `Customer customer` then?

Comment: because XXX class object not available at that time

Comment: i dont wan't want to map that object

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your POJO is called `Customer` and that you have something similar to this [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-basic.html), then you can use :

```
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
Customer myCustomer = session.load(Customer.class, <THE_ID_YOU_ARE_LOOKING>);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```